# comparing kinect 1 with kinect 2 in using ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I have a questions, hope everyone help me:
I don't know that kinect 2 is supported by ROS library? or only kinect is supported by ROS library.
If so, then what are their names if I use navigation, gmapping package?
Many thank for your supports

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242077/comparing-kinect-1-with-kinect-2-in-using-ros/) by [nguyennhubientdh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27795/nguyennhubientdh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the Kinect v2 with ROS: Take a look at `iai_kinect2` from https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2. You need also `libfreenect2`, a driver for linux for kinect v2 from here https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2.

Just follow the installation guide on the github pages. First install `libfreenect2` and make sure it works correctly. Kinect v2 only works on USB 3.0 interfaces. After that install the ros bridge `iai_kinect2`.

Once the pipeline is set up, you can display the colored pointcloud in rviz :-)

---

Originally posted by [easyspidy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26933/easyspidy/) with karma: 46 on 2016-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2